# Split and delete some data to another textbox

Tags: c#

I have incoming serial data like my screenshot below.
I want to split data from richtextbox (that have any string there) to another textbox (the one below richtextbox). but I only take any part of them, actually string after C. I want to delete 12 first string and then put them to another textbox.

FYI, my program is a RFID Reader and this is how my program works:

when I click select tag send, serial will send data and place them to richTextBox.
e.g data is 01018200000C000000000000000000000003 and I want 000000000000000000000003 go to another textbox (because this is the tag ID, and characters before it are message detail).
After that I click send and next data will showed on richTextBox then newest tag ID will replace first tag ID in textBox, and so on.

If data from serial not error, it will always send me format like that and I need to grab tag ID only so that's why I need to delete first 12 characters. But if error serial send me only 4 characters.

Anyone know easy way to do that?
I have tried some codes but there is still error
this is my code:

```
private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.rtbIncoming.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            string[] newData = text.Split('C');

            tagBox.Text = newData[1];

        }

        this.rtbIncoming.Text += text;

    }
```

[image]

Edit:

after investigating any further, there is an error in the data that I have received, and after I assure data received appropriate, I think all the answers are works to me. But I choose answer from Pranav-BitWiser to skipping data, because using split at 'C' character will make more difficult if tag ID have 'C' character on it.
Thanks for your answers, it really helpful :)

Comment: Sure, I know an easy way. Read each line into a string, split on the character 'C'. If you want more help, post the code that you've tried, the error you got, and what you don't understand about how to fix the error.

Comment: everytime you want to delete first 12 characters of a string?

Comment: Do you want to do it with all the lines or a particular line? How do you know which line you want to split and put in another `TexBox`?

Comment: @iheanyi yes, I've included my code.

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser if the data from serial right, I'll always delete first 12 characters, but when I'm got an error I only get 4 characters from serial.

Comment: @Abhishek when I click send, serial gave me a line, then click again serial gave me again, so first data from serial that go to texttbox must be replaced by second data incoming, and so on

Comment: You can't guarantee when serial data will arrive or how much will be present. So before you go splitting and decimating strings with abandon, you should ensure that when you read the string, it actually contains data, and data of a particular length that you desire, and actually contains the character on which you'd like to split.

Comment: @iheanyi yes! actually there were some delayed sending data and the characters length are different, I think because of CR-LF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always delete first 12 characters from string then you can use:

```
 string data = "01018200000c000000000000000000000003";
 TextBoxID.Text= data.Remove(0, 12);
```

OR

```
TextBoxID.Text = new string(data.Skip(12).ToArray());
```

Here- `TextBoxID` is the ID of your TextBox

Comment: Thanks for your help.
First code give me error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code` . second code worked, but sometime textBox showing right characters, sometime it's empty.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using your second method, skipping 12 characters and it's works. BTW, thanks for showing my image :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
string data = "01018200000c000000000000000000000003"; string[] splitdata = data.Split('c'); textBox2.Text = splitdata[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Actually I did this before, but it give me error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: Put a break point in the second line and debug it. Then check the values in the array "splitdata" after performing the split operation

Comment: Thanks! I'm adding `\n` to make sure the data correct :)

Answer (score 1):

If 12 characters are fixed you can use [substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)

```
String input = "01018200000c000000000000000000000003";
String portion = input.Substring(13); // Note the 0 based index 
Console.WriteLine(portion); // Verify test
```

Now you can use `portion`on your required textbox

```
textbox_one.Text = portion;
```

Edit : if your String is not fixed length try something like this [taking it has same format] + Will determine error state

Quoting :

> If data from serial not error, it will always send me format like that and I need to grab tag ID only so that's why I need to delete first 12 characters. But if error serial send me only 4 characters.

Suggestion:

```
String input = "01018200000c000000000000000000000003"; // This is input you get
String portion;

if(input.Length > 4){ 
    if(input.IndexOf("c")!=0){
          portion = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("c")+1); // Note the 0 based index 
          Console.WriteLine(portion); // Verify test
          textbox_one.Text = portion;
   }
   else{
         // Not a valid tag
         textbox_one.Text = "Error Tag :" + input;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code is works at first I click send, on second send it give me error `startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.`

Comment: is your string have the same length all the time ?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response!
your updated answer is now like Pranav-BitWiser, sometime textBox showing right characters, sometime it's empty, sometime wrong characters. e.g it show 000000000000000000000003, sometimes 003, sometimes empty :(

Comment: It has to be,, As I told, your scanning string should have same format to get this work. In my case I try to extract later part from character c onward.. which is why you see the behavior.. I you can put some example strings you get for this scanning process

Comment: Check the updated answer. i tried to identify Error tag case using return string length.. It should work now :)

Comment: Thanks! actually there were some error on data received and your answer are correct. I'm sorry make you trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string serialData;
serialData = "01018200000C000000000000000000000003";
textBox.Text = serialData.Split('C')[1];
serialData = //Your new serial data here
textBox.Text = serialData.Split('C')[1];
```

I hope split function helps. This will work only if your string has one "C". If it has more than one C, it splits wherever a C occurs in the string. Can you confirm if your string has only one C or more than one Cs?

Comment: using split at 'C' character will make more difficult if tag ID have 'C' character on it. Thanks for your answers :)